# Ansible. Parse yaml. Getting a value from a string

Tags: regex, ansible, yaml

How do I get the mac address 00 50 79 66 68 04 from the string that is contained in the following variable?

```
"oid.stdout_lines": [
       "iso.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1.0.80.121.102.104.4 \"00 50 79 66 68 04 \""
   ]
```

Comment: Desired result:        00 50 79 66 68 04

Comment: It would help if you specified an OS, a language, or stated no preference for language. Show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *regex_replace*. For example

```yaml
  _regex: '.*"(.*)"'
  _replace: '\1'
  mac: "{{ oid.stdout_lines|first|regex_replace(_regex, _replace)|trim }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  mac: 00 50 79 66 68 04
```